# dc.js scatterplot is slow with a lot of data - any alternative implementations?

Tags: scatter-plot, dc.js

I am using the scatterplot type in `dc.js`. It does a great job but whenever I go beyond 10k points it becomes very laggy and loses the smoothness I'm used to in `dc.js`.

Is there an alternative implementation of this plot within `dc.js` or will I have to resort to using a different library for that one ? If different library, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, tens of thousands of DOM elements and you run into trouble.

Could you please try out [this pull request for a canvas-based scatterplot](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1361) and leave a review on the ticket?

It should be easy to paste into your copy of dc.js if you don't want to do the git magic.

We just need to port it to D3v4 and add a couple tests and it will be ready to merge.

Comment: Yes I used it and it is much faster. Will comment on github.